# O meu programa continua a ir abaixo

Tags: c, debug, codeblocks

Não sei o porquê disto acontecer mas necessito de ajuda para perceber o porquê de o programa estar a crashar. O meu programa pretende usar o algoritmo de Kruskal para encontrar os caminhos mais leves entre cidades (aeroportos e estradas). Para isto, cria uma grafo não dirigido que liga os vértices com os arcos atribuidos.

Código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Uma estrutura para representar um arco pesado no grafo.
struct Edge {
    int src, dest, weight;
};

// Uma estrutura para representar um grafo ligado, não dirigido e pesado.
struct Graph {
    // V -> Número de vértices (Número de cidades), E -> Número de arcos (Número de estradas + conecções por aeroportos).
    int V;
    int E;

    // O grafo é representado como um array de arcos.
    // Visto o grafo ser não dirigido, o arco
    // da origem (src) ao destino (dest) é igual
    // ao arco de dest a src. Ambos são contados como 1 arco.
    struct Edge* edge;
};

// Cria um grafo com V vértices e E arcos.
struct Graph* createGraph(int V, int E)
{
    struct Graph* graph;
    graph->V = V;
    graph->E = E;
    graph->edge = (struct Edge*)malloc(E * sizeof(struct Edge));
    return graph;
};

// Uma estrutura para representar um subconjunto para as funções "find" e "Union".
struct subset {
    int parent;
    int rank;
};

// Função que procura pelo nº de vezes que o elemento i aparece.
int find(struct subset subsets[], int i)
{
    // Encontra a raíz e torna a raíz o predecessor de i.
    if (subsets[i].parent != i)
        subsets[i].parent
            = find(subsets, subsets[i].parent);

    return subsets[i].parent;
}

// Função que une os conjuntos x e y.
void Union(struct subset subsets[], int x, int y)
{
    int xroot = find(subsets, x);
    int yroot = find(subsets, y);

    // Agrega a árvore com rank pequeno sob a raíz da árvore com rank maior (Union by Rank).
    if (subsets[xroot].rank < subsets[yroot].rank)
        subsets[xroot].parent = yroot;
    else if (subsets[xroot].rank > subsets[yroot].rank)
        subsets[yroot].parent = xroot;

    // Se os ranks forem os mesmos, tornar um deles na raíz e incrementar a sua rank por 1.
    else
    {
        subsets[yroot].parent = xroot;
        subsets[xroot].rank++;
    }
}

// Compara 2 arcos de acordo com os pesos.
// Usado na função "qsort" para ordenar o array de arcos.
int myComp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    struct Edge* a1 = (struct Edge*)a;
    struct Edge* b1 = (struct Edge*)b;
    return a1->weight > b1->weight;
}

// Função principal para construir a MST usando o algoritmo de Kruskal.
void KruskalMST(struct Graph* graph)
{
    int V = graph->V;
    struct Edge
        result[V]; // Guarda a MST resultante.
    int e = 0; // Variável de índice, usada para o result[].
    int i = 0; // Variável de índice, usada para arcos ordenados.

    // 1º pass: Ordenar todos os arcos por ordem crescente dos pesos.
    // Se não podemos alterar o grafo dado, copiamos o array de arcos original.
    qsort(graph->edge, graph->E, sizeof(graph->edge[0]),
          myComp);

    // Alocar memória para criar V subconjuntos.
    struct subset* subsets
        = (struct subset*)malloc(V * sizeof(struct subset));

    // Criar V subconjuntos com 1 só elemento.
    for (int v = 0; v < V; ++v) {
        subsets[v].parent = v;
        subsets[v].rank = 0;
    }

    // Número total de arcos possível = V-1.
    while (e < V - 1 && i < graph->E) {
        // 2º passo: Escolher o arco mais leve.Pick the smallest edge.
        // Incrementar o índice para a próxima iteração.
        struct Edge next_edge = graph->edge[i++];

        int x = find(subsets, next_edge.src);
        int y = find(subsets, next_edge.dest);

        // Se a inclusão do arco não causa um ciclo, incluí-lo no result [] e,
        // incrementar o índice do result[] para o arco seguinte.
        if (x != y) {
            result[e++] = next_edge;
            Union(subsets, x, y);
        }
        // Senão, descartar o arco.
    }

    printf("Arcos da MST:\n");
    printf("V1   V2  Custo\n");
    int minimumCost = 0;
    int nRoads = 0;
    int nAirports = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < e; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d -- %d == %d\n", result[i].src,
               result[i].dest, result[i].weight);
        if (result[i].src == 0 || result[i].dest == 0) {
            nAirports++;
        }
        else {
            nRoads++;
        }
        minimumCost += result[i].weight;
    }
    printf("Minimum Spanning Tree com custo minimo: %d\n",minimumCost);
    printf("Numero de aeroportos: %d\n",nAirports);
    printf("Numero de estradas: %d",nRoads);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int V = 0; // Número de vértices(cidades) no grafo.
    int A = 0; // Número de aeroportos.
    int e = 0; // Número de estradas no grafo.
    int E = 0; //Númeto total de arcos no grafo.
    int cidade, aeroporto, cidade1, cidade2, custo = 0;

    printf("Introduza o numero de cidades: \n");
    scanf("%d", &V);
    printf("Introduza o numero de aeroportos: \n");
    scanf("%d", &A);
    printf("Introduza o numero de estradas: \n");
    scanf("%d", &e);

    E = A + e;

    struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V, E);

    for (int i = 0; i < A; i++) {
        printf("Introduza o custo do aeroporto: \n");
        scanf("%d %d", &cidade, &aeroporto);

        graph->edge[i].src = cidade;
        graph->edge[i].dest = 0; // vértice "céu"
        graph->edge[i].weight = aeroporto;
    }

    for (int j = A; j < A + E; j++) {
        printf("Introduza o custo da estrada: \n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &cidade1, &cidade2, &custo);

        graph->edge[j].src = cidade1;
        graph->edge[j].dest = cidade2;
        graph->edge[j].weight = custo;
    }

    KruskalMST(graph);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Olha, enviei um reposta, mas fiquei pensando, duas alocações assim pode dar problema, talvez alocar primeiro só o princilpa, se nó na hora de usar o egde você faz uma alocação, deixando no CreateGraph apenas como NULL no edge, assim vocÊ sabe que não foi alocado. Apenas que tenha uma unica chamada do CreateGraph ai tudo bem. também fecharia if(graph ==  NULL) depois da alocação, se alguma alocação falhar pode quebrar o sistema toda.

Comment: Obrigado pelas sugestões, vou implementá-las

Answer (score 0, accepted):

João veja este trecho aqui

```
struct Graph* createGraph(int V, int E)
{
    struct Graph* graph;[[(struct Edge*)malloc(E*sizeof(struct Edge))]aqui também]
    graph->V = V;
    graph->E = E;
    graph->edge = (struct Edge*)malloc(E * sizeof(struct Edge));
    return graph;
};
```

o struct Graph * também é um ponteiro, se você não allocar com malloc aqui no começo também, o porgrama não sabe aonde aramazenar grapho->V e ->E... e qualquer outro valor adiante.

Se usar linux, compile com a flag gcc -g ... e depois da gdb ./file.out para debugar.
b numeor_da_linha (break point)
disp nome_da_variavel - para ver a variavel
n (para seguir para proxima instrucao)
run (para começar)
quit (para sair)
help (manual)

São as instruções mais usadas.

Se estiver em outro sistema e precisar testar rapido tem este site abaixo:
https://www.onlinegdb.com/

lá voce clica na linha, define os break points executa com modo de depuração, da run  e vai testando linha a linha. Do lado direito ficam as variaveis, para codigos mais curtos é bem conveniente para testar ai e uma mão na roda.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas consegui implementar uma solução. Vou usar o site que recomendou para isso